# How do i re organise the sequence of Columns in MYSQL via Console

Tags: mysql

I have a WAMP stack

I have Windows 7 64bit Ultimate

I'm working on a table within a database of mine
and i've just realized that i now need to re organise the order of my columns

i could just retype the whole thing, but i was curious as to how i would do this
Automatically

i found a related question in stack overlow that said to use this syntax

```
ALTER TABLE foo MODIFY COLUMN Hobby VARCHAR(20) FIRST;
```

i did try it,  it didn't work

My Table is Layed out as follows

```
ID
DESCRIPTION
URL
USERNAME
PASSWORD
COMMENTS
```

Or More appropriately

```
ID  
DESCRIPTION  
URL   
USERNAME    
PASSWORD    
COMMENTS
```

What i'm trying to achieve is this

I want to take the column "url" and i want to relocate it after "comments"

in doing all this, i would aslo like to understand the syntax to re order it any which way i see fit

the Line i used (that did not work) was as follows

```
ALTER TABLE logins MODIFY COLUMN url VARCHAR (500) FIFTH;
```

Any suggestions

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: The order of columns is totally meaningless. Why do you want to do that? And please use the `{}` button to format your code.

Comment: @raphael  that's the exact one i tried,  didn't work.  My Table Name is  "logins" the column name is "url" it's currently in 3rd Position, i want it to be in 6th Position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify with `AFTER`, `BEFORE` to change order.

```
ALTER table logins modify column url VARCHAR(500) AFTER Comments;
```

Comment: Beutiful, Thanks a bunch, really appreciate it  i  used {ALTER TABLE logins MODIFY COLUMN url VARCHAR(500) AFTER comments;}  i also noticed that i actually did leave a space between VARCHAR and (500). thanks, that fixed my issue

Comment: @ a horse with no name  i added the parenthesis.. sorry  regarding your question, i understand why you would say that, and i agree, that (to the database) it makes no difference,  but. when i view it from console and do this {SELECT * FROM logins;} ,when i view the output and the URL's are really long, to me it makes a big difference.  see my point, thanks for your feedback anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ALTER TABLE 'TableName'
CHANGE Column 'columnname' 'columnnametoberegorganize' VARCHAR(500) AFTER 'ColumnName';
```